# neo4j REST API slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j 2.0.0M4 community edition with Node.js with https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j to access the Neo4j DB server over REST API by passing Cypher queries.

I have observed that the data returned by Neo4j from the webadmin of neo4j and even from the REST APi is pretty slow. for e.g.
a query returning 900 records takes 1.2s and then subsequent runs take around 200ms. 
and similarly if the number of records go upto 27000 the query in the webadmin browser takes 21 sec.

I am wondering whats causing the REST API to be so slow and also how to go about improving the performance?
a) It's using the CYPHER? the jSON parsing or
b) the HTTP Overhead itself as similar query with 27000 records returned in mysql takes 11 ms

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Which requests are you executing? The first query will warm up the db-caches so it is slower (and has to be parsed too).

Answer (score 3):

Neo4j 2.0 is currently a milestone build that is not yet performance optimized.

Consider [enabling streaming](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-streaming.html) and make sure you use [parameterized Cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-cypher.html#rest-api-send-queries-with-parameters).

For large result sets the browser consumes a lot of time for rendering. You might try the same query using cURL to see a difference.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for your suggestion. I tried the stable version and was using parameterized query but it seems the data still takes a long time for returning (14s) which is a lot as compared to mysql which takes 3sec for the same number of uses.

Comment: The number of rows returned are 27000 but most of the data over REST API is having links about querying the relationships like traverse, etc of individual nodes which I don't want, I am not sure how to get rid of them? Additionally i setted my configuration params for neo4j as below thinking it might help. However it didn't helped in much as well:                                  neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=250M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=2048M
and neo4j-wrapper.conf with:

wrapper.java.initmemory=1024
wrapper.java.maxmemory=8192

Comment: returning nodes or rels is very noisy, use id(node) or individual property names in the return instead. For tuning, check out http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/embedded-configuration.html.